# How to preselect twitter bootstrap dropdown option using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's say I want option C preselected when I load the page with a hash value of C appended to the URL (ex. http://www.example.com/#C).

I know how to get the value from the hash, but I'm having trouble on selecting the option.

I tried the following using jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown ul > li > a:contains("C")').click();
$('.dropdown ul > li > a:contains("C")').trigger('click');
```

but the value selected on the dropdown menu doesn't change

```
<div class="dropdown open" style="float:none;margin-top:5px;" id="select-group-0">
  <input type="hidden" value="A" name="your-category" id="undefined" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required">
  <a id="contactform_type" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-filter fp_input contactform_dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">A</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-filter">
     <li><a tabindex="-1" data-value="A">A</a></li>
     <li><a tabindex="-1" data-value="B">B</a></li>
     <li><a tabindex="-1" data-value="C">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it likely that your click trigger is firing before bootstrap is applied. check when it's called and delay if necesary. Also, you dont need `.trigger('click')` simply calling `.click()` with no params is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure wether you're trying to change the selected value of the dropdown to "C", or just highlight "C" in the dropdown list... Assuming you're trying to "*change the selected value of the dropdown to C*", you can use something like this..

```
/* update dropdown text when item clicked */
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText);
});

/* preselect value */
var selectedValue = "C";
$('.dropdown ul > li > a:contains("'+selectedValue+'")').parent('li').addClass("active");
$('.dropdown ul > li > a:contains("'+selectedValue+'")').trigger('click');
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/118698

If you're only try to highlight "C" in the dropdown list, you'd just remove the call to trigger('click').